# Most simple javadoc documentation for a derived exception regarding checkstyle SUN convention?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, checkstyle

I create a lot of exception classes, extending "Exception" and creating all constructors matching the constructors of the superclass "Exception". Eclipse generates this:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package pone.interfaces;


/**
 * @author wnck
 *
 */
public class FancyException extends Exception {

/**
 * 
 */
public FancyException() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param message
 */
public FancyException(String message) {
    super(message);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param cause
 */
public FancyException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param message
 * @param cause
 */
public FancyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param message
 * @param cause
 * @param enableSuppression
 * @param writableStackTrace
 */
public FancyException(String message, Throwable cause,
        boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
    super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

I don't want to document all param tags because the constructors just match semantically the constructors of the base class.

How can this fact be documented in a fast, clean and simple way using javadoc AND matching the SUN checkstyle rules?

Regards wnck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm afraid it may not be possible using Javadoc and matching the Sun Checkstyle rules.

This is because the [`@inheritDoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#inheritDoc) Javadoc tag does not reliably work with constructors (they are not inheritable). Also, Checkstyle does not recognize `@inheritDoc` on constructors. Instead, your best bet would be to exclude the constructors of your exception classes from the *JavadocMethod* requirement using Checkstyle configuration.

The latter could be achieved by setting the `tokens` property of the *[JavadocMethod](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod)* check to just `METHOD_DEF` and omitting `CTOR_DEF`. For exception classes, it may also make sense to simply [suppress](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#SuppressionFilter) the *JavadocMethod* check entirely, as exceptions probably don't contain any methods that really need explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
```

You can read about this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is: don't, and look into disabling that rule in checkstyle for at least those constructors. Everyone knows what they do or can easily look this up. Spend your effort on providing documentation that's actually useful.